# Why do I get a sort of strip passing through the frame title when using the dvipsnames option of xcolor in beamer?

Tags: beamer, color, frame-title, structure

Consider the following minimal example:

```
\documentclass[9pt, xcolor=dvipsnames]{beamer}

\mode<presentation>
{
  \usetheme{Frankfurt} 
  \usecolortheme[named=OliveGreen]{structure}
}


\begin{document}

\begin{frame}       
    \frametitle{Test title}     
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

I get surprisingly a sort of strip passing through the frame title when using, for instance, the OliveGreen color. This issue somehow disappears when using a classical color such as blue or green. Any thoughts how this could be fixed?

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can avoid the problem by explicitly selecting a colour model:

```
\RequirePackage[cmyk,dvipsnames]{xcolor}
\documentclass[9pt]{beamer}
\mode<presentation>
{
  \usetheme{Frankfurt} 
  \usecolortheme[named=OliveGreen]{structure}
}


\begin{document}

\begin{frame}       
    \frametitle{Test title}     
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

[image]